# ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to export data from Hive using spark scala. But I am getting following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource
```

My scala script is like below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM sparksdata")
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/root/Desktop/home.csv")
```

I have also try this command but still is not resolved please help me.

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0
```

Comment: Have you added `hive` to the `classpath` on every node?

Comment: @Mandy8055  No could explain me where I need to add in details.

Comment: Where and how do you run that script ? What version of Spark are you using ?

Comment: @eliasah I have created one scala file and command prompt execute this script.   Version : scala> util.Properties.versionNumberString
res2: String = 2.10.5

Comment: What is that command ? That is my question... Please create a complete minimum and verifiable example so we can help you !

Comment: @eliasah Please check this one  spark-shell -i /root/Desktop/spark.scala

Comment: I think you should give this one a try:http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-add-jars-to-standalone-pyspark-program-td22685.html

Comment: Have you tried 'format("csv")' ?

Comment: @Fabich I am getting following error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: csv.DefaultSource

Comment: What version of Spark are you using ? **(Spark not Scala)**

Comment: If the solution provided solves your problem, please accept it to close the issue as I see that none of your questions have been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to run that script the way you are running it, you'll need to use the `--jars` for local jars or `--packages` for remote repo when you run the command.

So running the script should be like this :

```
spark-shell -i /path/to/script/scala --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0
```

If you'd also want to stop the spark-shell after the job is done, you'll need to add :

```
System.exit(0)
```

by the end of your script.

**PS:** You won't be needing to fetch this dependency with **spark 2.+**.

Comment: Sir why `spark-submit` will not suffice in this case?Something like:`spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0 my_script.py`

Comment: I didn't say it won't suffice, it would be an overkill and unnecessary and also doesn't answer the OPs question. spark-shell -i allows quick prototyping without the need of building an application and downloading dependencies...